# How to display meaningful information from an object in the text box?

Tags: custom-object, page-layout

I have an object A, which has a lookup reference to object B.  Object B contains RecordId as the `Name`, which also happens to be an AutoNumber.  [image]

So when I edit object A (using standard layout) and select an object B, it pops back a the `RecordId` (A-00906 in this case).  Is there a way to show meaningful information, like `Account, Address 1`?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, no, not without using Visualforce and creating your own Edit pages. By default, the UI displays the sObject.Name field, which in your case is an auto-number.

Option 1: If you wanted, you could create a Visualforce page and a custom Lookup solution which stores the sObject.Id in the background and displays a user-friendly field instead.

Option 2: Change the Name field to Text and move the auto-number to a custom field.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, the only searchable field in a lookup search on a custom object is the Name field, [as outlined here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=search_fields_lookup.htm&language=en_US). You might consider voting up this IdeaExchange idea:

[Making other fields criteria available when you search using Lookup function](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000jehvAAA)